# Select distinct by one column ordered by time

Tags: sql, questdb

I have this table:

| ID | ParentNumber | ObjectNumber | Start | Component | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4b8cf664-0ef9-44b2-a266-6c27079b90ed | 2 | 1 | 2023-08-10T12:50:03.716000Z | 1 | ... |
| 92847bf9-dbfc-46ff-a9bb-b2210df66507 | 2 | 1 | 2023-08-11T17:13:30.716000Z | 1 | ... |
| fa9e0823-4432-480f-bbff-fbdac16a53fe | 2 | 1 | 2023-08-10T13:06:06.716000Z | 2 | ... |
| 9f3d4140-d8cc-4e01-8221-0991d2cc0ea4 | 2 | 1 | 2023-08-10T10:45:03.716000Z | 3 | ... |
| 02b70a62-77b7-4133-83a7-6c76d6cf7204 | 2 | 1 | 2023-08-12T09:26:22.716000Z | 3 | ... |
| 0cb48763-8bc1-4a10-8be4-721c8644dd94 | 2 | 1 | 2023-08-14T08:12:42.716000Z | 3 | ... |

I want to select rows where `ParentNumber = 2` & `ObjectNumber = 1`.

The hard part is that I want to select the latest entry distinct by `Component`. So I want to only get those rows:

| ID | ParentNumber | ObjectNumber | Start | Component | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 92847bf9-dbfc-46ff-a9bb-b2210df66507 | 2 | 1 | 2023-08-11T17:13:30.716000Z | 1 | ... |
| fa9e0823-4432-480f-bbff-fbdac16a53fe | 2 | 1 | 2023-08-10T13:06:06.716000Z | 2 | ... |
| 0cb48763-8bc1-4a10-8be4-721c8644dd94 | 2 | 1 | 2023-08-14T08:12:42.716000Z | 3 | ... |

I tryed to group by `Component` but with that I have the problem that I can't get all the other informations of those rows...

How can I get those rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by first obtaining the most recent start for each component and then joining it to the table.

```
select m.*
from mytable m
inner join (
  select Component, max(Start) as latest_Start
  from mytable
  where ParentNumber = 2 and ObjectNumber = 1
  group by Component
) as l on l.Component = m.Component and l.latest_Start = m.Start
```

Comment: That's a generic way to do it on any SQL database and it should work, but questdb has a built in keyword specifically for this scenario, as it is very common when using time series. I added an alternative answer

Answer (score 1):

Since QuestDB is built for time series it has a specific keyword for this use case. You can use `LATEST ON` as in

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE LATEST ON start PARTITION BY component
```

You can also add a where clause (if goes before the `LATEST ON` keyword) if needed.

More info at https://questdb.io/docs/reference/sql/latest-on/

More info at